# how to remove brs in a given script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I'm using phonegap and am very new to this.

script source:

```
<script src="http://www.transfermate.com/en/exchange_rates_api.asp"></script>
```

I'm trying to get rid of the < br >s in the div 'currency_converter_calculator_subscribe_form_under_info'

My attempt so far:

```
$('#currency_converter_calculator_subscribe_form_under_info.form_under_info calculator_subscribe_form_under_info br').remove();
```

**EDIT** The problem is the script produces a string like this:

```
4 USD United States of America Dollars
=
3.1308 EUR Euro
```

I need the line to not take up as much space, so I need to get rid of the < br >s or shorten the string. I know that after the number there will be a 3 character length acronym always e.g. USD, EUR. It would also work to parse out the part of the string after this char code and before the = sign either but I can't reference the label properly or so it would seem:

```
$('#currency_converter_calculator_subscribe_form_under_info').val('testing');
```

Best possible solution would be:

```
4 USD = 3.1308 EUR
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function removeBr(container) {
  var brs = container.getElementsByTagName("br");
  for (var i = 0; i < brs.length; i++) { brs[i].parentNode.removeChild(brs[i]); }
}
```

where container is your container ID

`var container = document.getElementById('currency_converter_calculator_subscribe_form_under_info');
    removeBr(container);`

Does this work for you?

Or if you don't wanna have an extra function you could use this in your CSS file to just make the 
 tags invisible
`br { display: none; }` or `#currency_converter_calculator_subscribe_form_under_info br { display: none; }` to make it effective only in the container you want.

Or you can also do a regex replace on your variable:

`var str = "4 USD<br> = <br>3.1308 EUR";
var newStr = str.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, " ");`

Or in Jquery:

`var str = "4 USD<br> = <br>3.1308 EUR";
var regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
$("#mydiv").html(str.replace(regex, " "));`

Comment: unfortunately not...I'm not sure where i should be calling this function, maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Your edit worked for me. This answered my original question. However I'm thinking now, I really need to parse the string. Can you see what I was doing wrong when trying to access the label's text?

Comment: well, i don't really have a full picture of your code, but I would guess after you assign your container the value

Comment: the value is assigned via the asp script. You can see all form elements there: http://www.transfermate.com/en/exchange_rates_api.asp

Comment: Yeah, there's so much code and I have no idea how you are getting that value from, ajax?

Comment: thank you the problem i'm having is that the str you have defined will obviously have to be dynamic so in order to define the variable str, I will have to access the label which it displays

Comment: that str that I defined can be the whatever string you use to produce your result you gave us in your question: ,4 USD United States of America Dollars
=
3.1308 EUR Euro`

Comment: Yeah there's a lot. I just put the script inside a div tag. <div id="Money" style='width:100%;height:90%;'>
         <div>
   <script src="http://www.transfermate.com/en/exchange_rates_api.asp"></script> 
            </div>
  </div> My problem is I don't know access the value which has been assigned

Comment: sorry forgot to '@'tag you in my response

Comment: Yeah, I have looked at your code. Sorry, the best solution you have is using the CSS styling. You're working with asynchronous code over here and frankly you're better off making an exchange converter on your own.
If they would of gave the output in a json array than it would be easier, but they want you to use their layout ;) So please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use find() to search for all br tags in that div and remove them

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.currency_converter_calculator_subscribe_form_under_info').find('br').remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="currency_converter_calculator_subscribe_form_under_info">

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  <br/>consectetur adipisicing elit.
  <br/>Obcaecati quos tenetur dolorum doloribus rerum
  <br/>ex ab dignissimos adipisci esse
  <br/>consequuntur facilis ipsam numquam
  <br/>officia officiis sit rem sint
  <br/>eligendi laudantium.
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It isn't working for the given script for me however